# show only file visiting buffers with certain file extension in centaur tabs

Tags: tabs, centaur-tabs

I am wondering for some time if it is possible to have [centaur tabs](https://github.com/ema2159/centaur-tabs) display only buffers with the same file extension as the current buffer. After spending some time using infamous search engine and building some half-knowledge reading centaur-tabs emacs lisp I decided to ask here.

Comment: You might want to ask on the Github site by opening an issue.

Comment: uh? My question is only public for 1 hour. is there any issue with asking here?

Comment: No, not at all. You might get an answer here. I am just suggesting that the author of `centaur-tabs` is the most likely person to know the answer and s/he might not be frequenting these parts.

Comment: i also asked here: https://github.com/ema2159/centaur-tabs/issues/223